# writing a script, making it executable then assigning it keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, backlight

I have a Samsung np700z5a and have managed to get most features working but would love to get the keyboard backlight keys working.

I have tried several methods including through the terminal. I have discovered that this works through the terminal:

```
echo 6 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

after an

```
sudo su
```

(but not, `sudo echo 6 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness` where I get `permissions denied`).

I have tried running this in AutoKey as this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

and assigned it to some keys in AutoKey but it did not work.

I noticed that when I tried to assign it to the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> key, this key and <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> where not recognised at all (these are the keys designated to turn the keyboard backlight up and down in a windows install) so I assigned it to <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> instead. As I said it does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
su <user> -c <command>
```

You will still have to provide the password, though.

Comment: not exactly sure what that means... But I typed: !/bin/bash su SIMON-700Z5A -c echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness , then assigned a key combination in auto hotkey. no dice.

Comment: Didn't it prompt you for a password?

Comment: didn't work at all. is what I wrote above what you were suggesting I write? not sure if that is my user name, i think it is the pc name. I just tried again and wrote in the terminal: su simon -c echo 6 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness but it says permission denied.

Comment: When you open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), it says `<user>@<host>:~#` at the beginning of the line. `<user>` is your username, `<host>` is the name of your computer.

Comment: As you have to do this as root, you should probably use `su root -c 'echo "6" > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness'`. :)
Also, be carefully with that `>`. A single `>` overwrites the file, while `>>` attaches the output to the end of it.

Comment: still no joy. permission denied. I guess I am just trying to get the sudo su command tiedin with the brightness command, which works fine from /home/simon# after a sudo su. I am happy to imput my password if that is what it takes. I just want to be ableto tun keyboard brightness on or off without having to go through the motions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same laptop model as user181401 (almost ten years later), and was trying to do something similar. While I'm not using AutoKey, I've been able to do what was asked, at least on Debian 12 LXQt; but I suspect it would also work on Ubuntu.

I was able to create two, one-line shell scripts, one that turns the keyboard backlight off, and one that turns the keyboard backlight up to its brightest. As long as I've given these shell scripts execute permission using sudo one time, they work just fine for me, executed directly from the desktop, even following a reboot, with no need to enter a password each time.

I put the following in a text file:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo 0 | tee /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Saved it in my Desktop folder, named it kbd_backlight_off.sh, then ran:

```
cd Desktop
sudo chmod u+x kbd_backlight_off.sh
```

Similarly, for the other one:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo 8 | tee /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

I saved it in my Desktop folder, named it kbd_backlight_max.sh, and then ran:

```
cd Desktop
sudo chmod u+x kbd_backlight_max.sh
```

Obviously, more complicated scripts could be written to make these increment/decrement the brightness from 0-8, but I haven't done that.

Btw, I recall that there used to be samsung-tools from the "Linux On My Samsung" project. It worked on Ubuntu and implemented the Fn keys, but I don't know how it works on current versions of Ubuntu. The repo still exists, but I haven't tried it: https://github.com/voria/samsung-tools

I also know that various desktop environments on Debian these days *just work* in terms of these Samsung Series 7 laptops' Fn keys. I believe Xfce, Cinnamon, GNOME, and Plasma all do. It just so happens that LXQt doesn't. Maybe it *just works* on Ubuntu these days, too?